# Libre Office writer How to print only page 2 of a 5 page writer document

Tags: printer, printing, libreoffice

My operating system is Windows 10, Printer is HP color laser jet CM1312nfi MPF, LibreOffice 7.5

I have created a Libre Office writer 5 page text document with 1 "picture"  a screen shot of a calendar monthly page.  Using LibreOffice all 5 pages of the the document prints as expected, ie. 5 individual pages are printed.
I also want to print ONLY page 2 of the document.  The only setting in LibreOffice that I find is to print the entire document. File > Print- shows settings to print entire document.  File> Printer settings shows correct HP printer settings.  File > Printer > Properties shows properties, but no option to select ODD pages, EVEN pages, OR CUSTOM- Normally where you can specify individual pages to print; ie 2 would print only page 2; 1,4 would print page 1 and 4. This is the format used in most print programs.

I have searched LibreOffice with different questions, but found no answers for how to print a "single" page of a document. Also, a Google search returned several answers how to print different things -- 2 pages on a single sheet, multiple copies, ect.

It is entirely possible I am asking the wrong question, but I have not been able to find an answer in LibreOffice.

Would appreciate suggestion(s), seems rather strange that LibreOffice would not make it easy to print a single page of a 5 page document.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't your print dialog contain a [**Range and Copies**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/swriter/guide/print_selection.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=WIN) section?

[image: Print Dialog]